# Xlsx Writer getting corrupted with Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am currently exporting a dataframe to an excel spreadsheet, but my one of my columns which has long strings with varying lengths cause the file to get corrupted.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('thing.xlsx'.format(path), engine='xlsxwriter',options={'strings_to_urls': False}) as writer:
```

Here I make put it into excel

```
df.to_excel(writer, 'long_text', index=False)
```

**Edit**

When I remove that column from the dataframe it ceases to corrupt, but I want to keep the column. When I limit the characters to 37 characters it also ceases to be corrupted. Which suggests that there is a character that is having trouble being encoded.

Any ideas as to how to handle this?

Comment: according https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa only 255 chars in column acceptable

Comment: okay that might be why, I'll try truncating the ones that have over 255 characters to see if that solves it

Comment: @simar Didn't solve it it. Only when I made it less than 37 characters did it dissapear, which makes me think that the problem is a specific character in the in the worksheet. Any way to encode these, or handle this type of psossibilites?

Comment: Is it at each row or just certain(means check 37 character)? Do u have any exceptin during exection?

Comment: @simar: The maximum **width** of the column is 255 characters but the cells can contain 32,767 characters. That limit is supported by XlsxWriter.

Comment: @Kalimantan XlsxWriter can handle any UTF-8 string that Excel can handle (which is all). Ensure that your string data is encoded as UTF-8. If you still have an issue then show a working example with input data. It is impossible to guess what the issue is from the current limited example. It doesn't relate to any known issues in XlsxWriter or any previously reported issue.

Answer (score 1):

as @jmcnamara remarked my issue was that one of my strings was not encoded in UTF-8, but after encoding all the strings the excel file ceased to be corrupted